# Adding Release Number to Web.config during release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to add the Predefined variable 'Release.ReleaseId'(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops) to a websites web.config during an IIS Pipeline release. XML variable substitution is enabled on the stage, but it is not replacing the Release.ReleaseId with anything.

[image: Picture of the setting in the web.config]

Comment: Could you try `Release.ReleaseId`?

Comment: I have tried it with both 'Release.ReleaseId' and 'RELEASE.RELEASEID', I changed it to the latter since  that matched exactly with what was in the 'Initialize job' step logs.

Comment: try with `_`: `Release_ReleaseId`

Answer (score 0):

You have set `value=1` for new key 'RELEASE.RELEASEID' but it's not related to the variable.

To add the variable value, you should set as below:

```
<add key="RELEASE.RElEASEID" value="__Release.ReleaseId__" />
```

You can refer to the [XML variable substitution example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution-example) for the details.

In addition, you can aslo use [Replace token extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace values in config file.